# No qualifying bean of typfound for dependency

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to inject multiple context to run my application, but the server crushed and I got the following log error:

```
'Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.ListableJobLocator] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100)'
```

I checked about the error, and I found some details [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-nosuchbeandefinitionexception), but I could not find the error in my code below:

The context to be loaded:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@ImportResource("classpath:job-report.xml")
public class DBDataManipulatorServiceContext {


@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setName("aircraft").setType(H2).build();
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    lef.setDataSource(dataSource);
    lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
    lef.setPackagesToScan("com");
    return lef;
}

@Bean
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.H2);
    return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new JpaTransactionManager();
}
```

}

the xml file to be imported:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd
">

<context:component-scan base-package="com" />

<!-- stored job-meta in memory -->
<bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

<bean id="jobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>

<bean id="Aircraft" class="com.domain.Aircraft" scope="prototype" />

<bean id="customReader" class="com.batch.CustomReader" />

<bean id="customWriter" class="com.batch.CustomWriter" />

<batch:job id="reportJob">
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="customReader" writer="customWriter"
                commit-interval="10">
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="runScheduler" class="com.RunScheduler" />

<!-- Run every Hour -->
<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <!-- <task:scheduled ref="runScheduler" method="run" fixed-delay="3600000" 
        /> -->
    <task:scheduled ref="runScheduler" method="run"
        cron="0 0 * * * *" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

the runScheduler is:

```
@Component
public class RunScheduler {

@Autowired
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Autowired
private Job job;

public void run() {

    try {

        String dateParam = new Date().toString();
        JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("date", dateParam).toJobParameters();

        JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, param);
        System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

My Custom reader:

```
public class CustomReader implements ItemReader<Map<Integer, Aircraft>> {

@Override
public Map<Integer, Aircraft> read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException,
        ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {

    HTMLDataExtractorService htmlDataExtractor = new HTMLDataExtractorService();

    Map<Integer, Aircraft> aircraftsMap = htmlDataExtractor.parsePage("/Sabri/DTDailyReport.html");

    return aircraftsMap;
}
```

}

and my customwriter: 
    public class CustomWriter implements ItemWriter{

```
@Override
public void write(List<? extends Aircraft> aircrafts) throws Exception {

    DBDataManipulatorServiceImpl dbDataManipulatorImpl = new DBDataManipulatorServiceImpl();

    Map <Integer, Aircraft> aircraftsMap = null;

    for(Aircraft aircraft: aircrafts){
        aircraftsMap.put(aircraft.getAircraftId(), aircraft);
    }
    dbDataManipulatorImpl.saveToDataBase(aircraftsMap);

}}
```

sorry for any inconvenient, but can anyone tell me where is my error, and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is spring*.batch.core.jar placed in classpath?

Comment: yep, all the needed dependencies are included in my pom

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following entry in the ApplicationContext.xml where jobLauncher and jobRegistry beans are declared solved the problem for me

```
<bean id="jobRegistry"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add @EnableBatchProcessing to your config, that is roughly equivalent to using the  XML namespace

Comment: This is a valid solution if you're using later versions of Spring. And will save you from having to add all the various beans for Spring Batch.